# Button on table header

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a problem with a old site and I need to place a button in a div element, but on the top of a table.

```
<div class="panel2" style="border: 1px solid red;">
    <div id="charInfo">
        <input type="button" id="lockList" name="lockList" value="Lock WL" />
        <table width="500px" style="border:1px solid #000;border-collapse:collae;font-familyrif;font-size:80%;">
            <caption style="font-size:140%;padding:5px;">Wish list status <b>Tyde</b>
            </caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Zone name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Wish Items</th>
                    <th scope="col">Received</th>
                    <th scope="col">Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr></tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scopre="row">Heart of Fear</th>
                    <td align="center">22</td>
                    <td align="center">0</td>
                    <td align="center" style="color:Green;"><b>Active</b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scopre="row">Mogu-shan Vaults</th>
                    <td align="center">27</td>
                    <td align="center">4</td>
                    <td align="center" style="color:Green;"><b>Active</b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scopre="row">Throne of Thunder</th>
                    <td align="center">45</td>
                    <td align="center">0</td>
                    <td align="center" style="color:Green;"><b>Active</b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scopre="row">Throne of Thunder (Heroic)</th>
                    <td align="center">5</td>
                    <td align="center">1</td>
                    <td align="center" style="color:Red;"><b>Not locked</b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div> </div>
```

I have a example here http://jsfiddle.net/TvwKz/

As you can see the button is placed to the right, but I want to have it placed on top of the table caption. Can it be done and if so how?
This is wat I want
[image]
<sub>(source: [odinsoft.dk](http://www.odinsoft.dk/download/Table.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Use `position: absolute` for button with `left: 450px`. For `#charInfo` use `position: relative`. [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TvwKz/3/)

Comment: Will not Work. The button is aligend to the page and not to the div. So the button don't adjust when the page changes.  If the table only is 300 px in with then the button is not on the caption any more.

Comment: Another solution: add row without borders at the top of table and place button in last cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can this

CSS

```
#lockList {width:auto;margin:auto;position: relative;}
```

HTML

```
<caption style="font-size:140%;padding:5px;">Wish list status <b>Tyde</b>
            <input type="button" id="lockList" name="lockList" value="Lock WL" />
            </caption>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ypAVr/

Comment: I do not need it on top of the row. I need it to be displayed where to caption is on the right hand site of the text.

Answer (score 1):

As referring to the fiddle link which you have give,
remove `float:right;` from `lockList` css class.

```
#lockList {width:auto;margin:auto;position: relative;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check with below CSS

```
#lockList 
{

    width:auto;
}
#charInfo
{
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;   
}
```

And fiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QyfQw/)

Comment: Botton is to the top right side as I hade it before. So it's not on the caption.